# Unable to inject a object into a class in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to setup dependency injection in my Objective C code like following:

```
#import <ToDoShared/ToDoListRepository.h>

@interface ToDoListService : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray<TreeNode *> *todoList;
@property (nonatomic, copy) ToDoListRepository *todoListRepository;
```

.m file:

```
    #import <ToDoShared/TreeNode.h>
    #import <ToDoShared/ToDoListRepository.h>
                
    @interface ToDoListService : NSObject
                
    @property (nonatomic, copy) ToDoListRepository *todoListRepository;
        
        #import "ToDoListService.h"
        
        @implementation ToDoListService
        
        - (instancetype) initWithTodoListRepository: (ToDoListRepository*) repository {
            self = [super init];
            if (self) {
                _todoList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                _todoListRepository = repository;
                [self getToDoListFromDataSource];
            }
            return self;
        }
```

I am calling above file from a Swift file with following object:

```
let viewModel = ToDoViewModel(toDoListService: ToDoListService(todoListRepository: ToDoListRepository()))
```

But when I try to use following method of Service file, it crashes:

```
[_todoListRepository saveNodeList:_todoList];
```

Crash Error:

```
Exception   NSException *   "-[FontServicesDaemonManager saveNodeList:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000000145b0" 0x0000600000cb5a10
name    __NSCFConstantString *  "NSInvalidArgumentException"    0x00000001e9c8a918
reason  __NSCFString *  "-[FontServicesDaemonManager saveNodeList:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000000145b0" 0x0000600002c38a00
userInfo    void *  NULL    0x0000000000000000
reserved    __NSDictionaryM *   3 key/value pairs   0x00006000002a9500
[0] (null)  "callStackReturnAddresses" : 40 elements    
[1] (null)  "osLogPack" : 104 bytes 
[2] (null)  "callStackSymbols" : 40 elements
```

The exception is not making sense to me at all. The instance is still there as it is not nil. But still it is not able to call the method. I have tried to use retain, copy and strong but nothing works for me. Anybody can give me any suggestion here?

**Edit:**

```
Tried different options but I am still getting: '-[__NSSingleObjectArrayI saveNode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000000087d0'
*** First throw call stack:
```

It is again on same line but now saying __NSSingleObjectArrayI, I have no idea what is __NSSingleObjectArrayI

Comment: The exception says that you have invoked `saveNodeList` on an instance of `FontServicesDaemonManager`, not your class.  You mention dependency injection, but there is no dependency injection that I can see; you are just passing an instance to the initialiser. Is there some dependency injection framework in use here that you haven't mentioned?  That could explain what is happening if it has injected the wrong class.

Comment: I have not used any framework and doing it manually. I am creating it like this for now.  let viewModel = ToDoViewModel(toDoListService: ToDoListService(todoListRepository: ToDoListRepository()))

Comment: Then something strange is definitely happening since the class you are invoking the method on in the objective c code isn't what it should be.  The property should be `(nonatomic, strong)`, not `(nonatomic, copy)`

Comment: I have tried it with debugger and when I am at the line [_todoListRepository saveNodeList:_todoList]; I can see that _todoListRepository exist but when it is executed it crashes. Also when I create a local variable of todoListRepository just before the crashing line and use it instead it works fine.

Comment: The pointer is getting messed up. Using `copy` could certainly explain that. You shouldn't use `copy` with reference types.

Comment: ok I have removed it but I am still getting the crash, please check edit, error is bit different now.

Comment: You have called `saveNode` on an instance of `NSSingleObjectArray`, which is part of the `NSArray` class cluster that objective C will use if an array contains a single object.  Of course `NSArray` doesn't have `saveNode` so again you have probably messed up pointers. Is there some particular reason you are using objective C instead of Swift for everything? You need to understand that Objective C has no type safety as it is a C derivative and you need to understand references and pointers.

Comment: Oh, and the crash isn't on the same line because before it was on an invocation of `saveNodeList` and now it is a crash on an invocation of `saveNode`, so you need to look at where you call `saveNode`, probably inside `saveNodeList`. Perhaps edit your question to show that function.

Comment: It is actually on same object, I tried to create a simple empty object saveNode, but it is still there

Comment: I have fixed it, I had to retain the object. So adding _repository = [repository retain]; in the initializer fixed it.

Comment: That doesn't look right.  With ARC you shouldn't need to manually retain or release objects. Declaring a property as `strong` should automatically retain it. Also, it is a bad idea to bypass setters and getters and access the underlying `_` ivar directly without good reason.

Comment: Actually this project is not using ARC, I know it sound weird but this is with manual memory management

Comment: Ok, if you aren't using ARC, then you are going to have to be very careful with your memory management. If you get it wrong you will get crashes (as you have seen) and leaks